# SQL Double Pivot With Sum

Tags: sql, pivot, sql-server-2017

I have a dataset in SQL server management studio 17 that requires some pivoting to collapse multiple rows into one row for ease of reading and saving space. Per unique id there are a set of codes which act as operators on the values, with the intention of displaying the results in a total column at the end. I've performed a primary pivot with one set of codes, but it looks like I need to do a second one to do further collapsing/amalgamation.

Here is some unpivoted data

```
PO_NUM   u_id   CODE_1   CODE_2   VALUE
---------------------------------------
0M274316 1      3        9;13     150
0N274316 1      9        9        200000
0O274316 1      6        9        210000
0P274316 1      6        13       21000
0Q274316 1      6        9        50000.5
0R274316 1      15       9        0
0M274317 2      3        9;13     150
0N274317 2      9        9        300000
0O274317 2      6        9        220000
0P274317 2      6        13       22000
0Q274317 2      6        8        90000.5
0R274317 2      15       8        0
```

With a sample pivot with the first unique id as an example I get:

```
PO_NUM    uid  CODE_1   CODE_2    6         9        15
-----------------------------------------------------
0M274316  1      3       9;13    210000    200000   0
0M274316  1              9       21000     NULL     NULL
0M274316  1              13      50000.5   NULL     NULL
```

What I need to do is another pivot to have '9;13' as columns with sums being used with the values. I have this initial pivot command as:

```
SELECT PO_NUM, CODE_1, CODE_2, VALUE from table
Pivot (max(VALUE) for CODE_2 in ([6],[9],[15])) pvt1
```

Which merges the data as expected when I don't include the CODE_1 vals. But trying to add the second pivot with CODE_2 just further messes the data. How do I pivot a second time using the pivoted data from the first command?
Expected output would be:

```
PO_NUM    uid    6         9        15    9;13    9(2)    13   total
------------------------------------------------------------------------
0M274316  1   281000.5   200000     0      150    null   null   481150.5
```

Basically they rows have been collapsed into one with the codes being broken out into columns. In reality the columns will be renamed to avoid conflicts with names, therefore I used 9(2) just to show the data is still there.

Sorry about the edits.

Comment: Please provide your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just use conditional aggregation:

```
select po_num, u_id, code_2,
       max(case when code_1 = 3 then value end) as [3],
       max(case when code_1 = 6 then value end) as [6],
       max(case when code_1 = 9 then value end) as [9],
       max(case when code_1 = 15 then value end) as [15]
from t
group by po_num, u_id, code_2;
```

I think this would be expressed using `pivot` as:

```
SELECT PO_NUM, u_id, CODE_2, [3], [6], [9], [15]
from table
Pivot (max(VALUE) for CODE_2 in ([3], [6], [9], [15])) pvt1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(PO_NUM VARCHAR(10),  u_id int,  CODE_1  varchar(10), CODE_2 varchar(10),  VALUE DECIMAL(18,2))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
('0M274316', 1, '3', '9;13', 150),
('0N274316', 1, '9', '9', 200000),
('0O274316', 1, '6', '9', 210000),
('0P274316', 1, '6', '13', 21000),
('0Q274316', 1, '6', '9', 50000.5),
('0R274316', 1, '15', '9', 0),
('0M274317', 2, '3', '9;13', 150),
('0N274317', 2, '9', '9', 300000),
('0O274317', 2, '6', '9', 220000),
('0P274317', 2, '6', '13', 22000),
('0Q274317', 2, '6', '8', 90000.5),
('0R274317', 2, '15', '8', 0)


SELECT *, [6] + [9] + [15] + [9;13] + [9(2)] + [13] as total FROM (

    SELECT PO_NUM,u_id, CODE + ( CASE WHEN DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY C ) > 1 THEN '(' + CAST (  C  AS varchar(50)) + ')' ELSE '' END ) CODE, VALUE 
    FROM (
        SELECT MIN(PO_NUM) OVER(PARTITION BY u_id) PO_NUM, u_id, 1 C, CODE_1 CODE, VALUE FROM @MyTable 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MIN(PO_NUM) OVER(PARTITION BY u_id) PO_NUM, u_id, 2 C, CODE_2 CODE, VALUE from @MyTable 
    ) T
) SRC
PIVOT(SUM(VALUE) FOR CODE IN ( [6], [9], [15], [9;13], [9(2)], [13])) PVT
```

Result:

```
PO_NUM     u_id        6            9           15        9;13      9(2)        13          total
---------- ----------- ------------ ----------- --------- --------- ----------- ----------- -------------
0M274316   1           281000.50    200000.00   0.00      150.00    460000.50   21000.00    962151.00
0M274317   2           332000.50    300000.00   0.00      150.00    520000.00   22000.00    1174150.50
```